# How can I set up Apple Mail on macOS to work with Gmail ActiveSync?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, exchange-activesync

I'd like to receive push Gmail emails. My organisation offers Gmail ActiveSync, and I was able to configure this to work easily on my iPhone. However I cannot seem to get it to work on my Mac.

If I try adding it bedding "New Account > Microsoft Exchange" I'm eventually hit with "Internal/External URL" which I do not have.

If I try adding it as a "Mail Account" it simply does not work, and I noted that that option has nowhere for me to enter the "domain" setting that I had to enter on iPhone.

Here are the settings that work on iPhone:

```
Email: email@gmail.organization.com
Password: Password
Username: Email: email@organization.com

Server: m.google.com
Domain: google
```

Thank you!

Comment: ActiveSync is for MS Exchange servers *only.* Use the Google option, for "push" or more correctly IMAP email.

Comment: Google has an ActiveSync option for paid users as it has disabled push outside the Gmail client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The macOS Mail app doesn't support ActiveSync**, as documented in the [Mail User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/add-or-remove-email-accounts-mail35803/mac) for macOS Big Sur 11:

[image]

Mail on macOS uses [Exchange Web Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-applications-and-the-exchange-architecture) instead, that's why you are requested to provide an "Internal/External URL", [usually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-set-the-ews-service-url-by-using-the-ews-managed-api) `https://<server name>/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

Since Microsoft Outlook [doesn't support ActiveSync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/outlook-cannot-use-activesync-connect-exchange) either, your only option is to configure the Mail app to use another protocol.

If the Gmail server behaves like Microsoft Exchange, you can specify the domain with this login string:

```
DOMAIN/USERNAME
```

as explained in [Understanding login strings with POP3/IMAP](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/understanding-login-strings-with-pop3-imap/ba-p/610683).